# how to avoid ajax hit make entries in history?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my application, every page have multiple ajax hit.
 So if  clicking the back button the browser treats every ajax hit as a page and render that hit again which makes the page reloads and actual page will not serve.
How to avoid ajax hit making entries in history? The following code im using for ajax

}

```
  if (modet == undefined) {
        xmlhttp.open('POST', url, mode);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(parameters);
    } else {
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, mode);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: Most probably you links (that trigger ajax calls) use `#` (hash) symbol. That is what causes your history to populate with them. If that's the case try removing them.

Comment: Ajax is not making entries to history. When you press back button, you must be accessing previous page (check any page that reloads content would not work than).