# Don't add Url to browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history, next.js

I read the information on the browser history and I understand that I do not have access to the array of history objects, and even more so I can not delete them. However, my task is to exclude the addition of parameterized URLs to history. I have tabs in my project, their URLs:

```
/profile,
/profile?menu=1
/profile?menu=2
```

I use nextjs framework in my project. His navigation code:

```
public handleOnClickItem(key: string) {
    const id = '1';
    const href = `/profile?id=${id}&menu=${key}`;
    Router.push(href, href, { shallow: true });
    // tabs are navigated
    Router.onBeforeHistoryChange = (url) => {
        console.log('App is changing to before history change: ', url);
    };
}
```

Can I not add this url to history? I get it in console.log. And as I understood from the description of the method, this URL should not yet go down in history.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is goal....have back button return to previous route before `profile` was navigated to?

Comment: example navigation: /home > /profile > /profile?menu='1' >  /profile?menu='2'  and when browser.back() => return to /home( from profile to home, as if ignoring the profile with the parameters, as if we were always on the same URL)

Comment: So you could think of this differently and keep track of where user came from when they navigated to profile and use `Router.beforePopState` to intercept

Comment: Thanks. I will deal with this

Comment: The person answered me correctly, but deleted it later, you just need to use replace instead of push. I apologize, return the answer, I note that it helped

Answer (score 4):

This should solve it:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace

> Similar to the replace prop in next/link, router.replace will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history stack.

Meanwhile keep in mind shallow routing option is used to trigger/not trigger next.js lifecycle methods (eg. getInitialProps) when doing the routing.

Answer (score -2):

Load your contents via AJAX once you're in the website, and do not keep updated URLs.

The downside to this is that your user's wouldn't be able to bookmark a specific page (no permalinks). In history it will only show the base url without parameters only.

There was [a similar post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801375/how-to-avoid-ajax-hit-make-entries-in-history)

Comment: What does this have to do with using next.js router?

Comment: I don’t quite understand how I can do this for myself. I recently worked with the reactjs and nextjs framework. In my project I use the next router call in handlers. But thanks anyway, for your answer, I will dig further